# How to fill missing high zoom level tiles from MapServer WMS?

Tags: wms, mapserver, tiles, mapproxy, getmap

I'm creating image tile pyramids (format = MRF) which do not contain all possible tiles at high zoom levels. This is because in some areas the high zoom level tile does not exhibit higher resolution than a lower zoom level tile. I'm not creating these because the saving in terms of computation time and storage is quite large.

I am serving these MRF files as a WMS using NASA's Onearth software and MapServer. When I make a GetMap request that would return image tiles at an incomplete zoom level, the missing tiles are of course shown as blank.

Is there a setup so that, for such a request, these missing tiles would be filled with portions of tiles from a lower zoom level? Is this something that MapProxy (which I know nothing about) might be able to help me with?

The obvious solution is to generate 'complete' image pyramids but I would lose my considerable savings.

Comment: When I see `tiles` and `WMS` together it makes me suspicious, is it really a WMS, or is it a WMTS?  I see that [Global Imagery Browse Services](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/about/science-system-description/eosdis-components/global-imagery-browse-services-gibs) , which is the replacement for OnEarth, doesn't use WMS.

Comment: @nmtoken OnEarth (which is a component of GIBS) does provide WMTS which I am providing as part of my setup. However I also have a requirement to provide WMS from the same source.

Comment: So should the line `I am serving these MRF files as a WMS using NASA's Onearth software and MapServer.` be changed to `as a WMTS`, sorry confused.  https://onearth.jpl.nasa.gov/ told me that OnEeath is replaced...

Comment: If I had a set of images and needed to create a WMS using MapServer, I would set up a group of layers each with different map scales.  Then use tileindex to group the images I wanted to show per layer.  Not sure if that would work in your case.

Comment: @nmtoken I think the situation is that OnEarth on it is own has ben replaced with GIBS, which encompasses OnEarth, MRF, etc (https://github.com/nasa-gibs). My WMS has a TIME dimension, and apparently an OnEarth module needs to be used in conjunction with MapServer in order to enable correct selection of MRF files by time value.

Comment: @nmtoken Thanks for the suggestion. I'm afraid I do not have experience with tileindex. In essence I think what I'm looking for is for imagery in missing tiles at high zoom levels to be extracted from the appropriate lower zoom level tile on the fly; would your tileindex setup suggestion provide this?

Comment: Take a look at the MapServer documentation http://mapserver.org/optimization/tileindex.html#tileindex